# Usb4Java:Listen when Device is Connected

Tags: java

I'm using Usb4Java Library for USB comunication, and I need to hear when a device is connected and then check with Vid and Pid if that's what I want and so connect to it, Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, please:

1) Check out the usb4java home page: http://usb4java.org/usb4java-javax/

2) Download (and, if necessary, build) the latest library and sample code versions

I believe this example illustrates what you're looking for:

https://github.com/usb4java/usb4java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/usb4java/examples/HotPlug.java

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for, Thanks. 
But now I need more help, I'm using Windows and here is saying that the libusb hotplug does not support this sistema,é that? It is not supported on Windows?